# AngularJs resetar para option padrão com ngOption

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ao acionar o metodo addAgent o item é adicionado mas a option selecionada continua e deveria voltar a ficar selecionado o option default.

Controller

```
$scope.addAgent = function (selectedAgent) {

    if (null == selectedAgent) {
        alert('Selecione um Agente para adicionar.');
        return;
    }

    $scope.agents.push(selectedAgent);
    //mesmo resetando aqui, o último option selecionado continua marcado
    $scope.selectedAgent = '';
};
```

View

```html
<label>Agentes</label>
 <select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="selectedAgent"
        ng-options="option as option.name 
        group by option.type for option in availableAgents track by option.id">

<option value="" ng-selected="selectedAgent ==''">Selecione</option>

</select>

<a ng-click="addAgent(selectedAgent)" 
 class="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Adicionar Agente"><i class="fa-plus fa"></i></a>
```

Exemplo Formato dos dados do ngOption

```html
var availableAgents =  [
 {id:1, name:"aaaa", "type":"A"},
 {id:2, name:"aaaa2", "type":"A"},
 {id:3, name:"bbbb", "type":"B"},
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você declarou a variável `$scope.agents` como um Array?  Eu copiei seu código para o Plunker e a única alteração que eu fiz foi declarar a variável como um Array.

Controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('appController', function($scope) {
  $scope.agents = [];
  $scope.availableAgents = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "aaaa",
    "type": "A"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "aaaa2",
    "type": "A"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "bbbb",
    "type": "B"
  }, ];

  $scope.addAgent = function(selectedAgent) {
    if (null == selectedAgent) {
      alert('Selecione um Agente para adicionar.');
      return;
    }

    $scope.agents.push(selectedAgent);
    //mesmo resetando aqui, o último option selecionado continua marcado
    $scope.selectedAgent = null;


  };

})
```

Html:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="selectedAgent"
        ng-options="option as option.name 
        group by option.type for option in availableAgents track by option.id">

<option value="" ng-selected="selectedAgent ==''">Selecione</option>

</select>

<a ng-click="addAgent(selectedAgent)" 
 class="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Adicionar Agente"><i class="fa-plus fa"></i>Adicionar</a>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eO3qJk0T4MZGFzBSddeL?p=preview)

Comment: o seu plunker não está completo.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade testa agora. Obrigado por avisar.

Comment: Só para visualizar melhor o funcionamento https://plnkr.co/edit/eO3qJk0T4MZGFzBSddeL?p=preview mas realmente, se a solução era só adicionar o $scope.agents, perfeito =D